# How can I test a PL/SQL function on a database where I do not have 'CREATE PROCEDURE' privileges?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to troubleshoot a PL/SQL stored procedure, written on a development database, that is malfunctioning on a *production* database.  I use SQLdeveloper for all of my coding and testing.

Apparently, a combination of conditions has caused a few rows of data to be missed during the query.  The problem data does not exist in the development database, only in the production DB; however, if I want to use SQLdeveloper to test this procedure and its fucntions, I can only connect to the development database.

My employer's IT security policy prohibits developers from having anything more than 'read only' privileges on production databases.  Even though my stored proc only contains **SELECT** statements, I still have to execute a **CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE** statement whenever I want to tweak the code and test any changes I make to it.  Obviously I cannot do this without the necessary privileges.

On the other hand, there is no *easy* way of populating the development database with the 'problem' data that exists in the production database.  It got there via a complicated sequence of transactions by a multitude of users.  And overwriting the development database with a copy of the production database requires an "Act of Congress" in my organization.

Bottom line: Is there some type of workaround, or must I wait for several weeks until the corporate DBAs do another 'refresh' of the development database?

Comment: Make another "development" database that is a copy of the production database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this. As you already know, the best solution will be to get the prod data in your dev. environment. In the meantime, you can try to 'debug' the procedure in prod by executing the select statements manually (without creating the whole proc) and try and figure out what's going on and where it breaks. You can try and use begin/end blocks with dbms_output and try to debug parts of the proc... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for replying!  I've been doing exactly that --- executing snippets of SQL from the offending functions --- and I believe I may have identified the problem data.  It was something that was improperly entered by one of our users.  In the meantime I am going to establish a process for expediting 'refreshings' of the dev db with prod data in case this type of scenario occurs again.